# Integrate $\int e^x \cosh(x) \: dx$ by parts

Tags: integration

I was presented with the following question:

> Evaluate: $$I:=\int e^x \cosh(x) \: dx$$

So we let $u=\cosh(x)$ and $v'=e^x$, therefore $u'=\sinh(x)$ and $v=e^x$.

Therefore $I:=e^x \cosh(x)-\int e^x \sinh(x)=e^x \cosh(x) - (e^x \sinh(x) - \int e^x \cosh(x)\: dx$

Thus: $I = e^x \cosh(x) - e^x \sinh(x) + I \implies 0 = e^x(\cosh(x)-\sinh(x))=e^x e^{-x} = 1$

How is this valid?

Comment: I would just use the definition of $\cosh(x)$, that is, $$\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}.$$ Then it's easy to integrate, and you don't even need to use parts.

Comment: Your manipulations are (useless and) correct since $I=I+e^x(\cosh x-\sinh x)+C$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wasn't sure if it was worth answering a few month old question but seeing as this was one of the first results that came on Google when searching about it I thought it might be helpful for anyone else looking as well. I'm only a student but If I'm not mistaken, following on from:

$$I:=∫e^x \ \cosh \ x\ dx,$$ therefore:
$$I =∫e^x \ \cosh \ x\ dx \ = \ e^x\ \cosh\ x\ -\ e^x\ \sinh\ x \ - ∫e^x\ \cosh\ x\ dx$$ 
$$I=∫e^x \ \cosh \ x\ dx \ = \ e^x\ \cosh\ x\ -\ e^x\ \sinh\ x \ - I$$ 
$$2I =2∫e^x\ \cosh\ x\ dx =  e^x\ \cosh\ x - e^x\ \sinh\ x + c, $$ so:
$$I =∫e^x \cosh\ x \ dx = {e^x \ \cosh\ x - e^x \ \sinh\ x + c\over 2}. $$

I think the problem was that if you added $I:=∫e^x\ \cosh\ x\ dx$ to right side, you needed to add it to the left as well.
On another note, I apologize for the lack of structure in the answer and formatting. Never had to use Mathjax before. Wish the basic tutorial was improved and made more user friendly.

Comment: This is the way I would have proceeded. Keep up the good work!

Comment: @Dmoreno This won't work because $\cosh''=\cosh$ and $(-1)(-1)=1$ in the integration by parts. Indeed, integration by parts yields $I=I+ e^x(\cosh(x)-\sinh(x))+C$ as Did already commented. Note that $\cos(x)-\sinh(x)=e^{-x}$. This works on $e^{-x}\cos(x)$ because $\cos''=-\cos$.

Comment: The third line should read $$I=e^x\cosh(x)-e^x\sinh(x) \color{Red}{+}I$$

Comment: You are right @Ian.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^x\cosh x=\frac{1}{2}e^x(e^x+e^{-x})=\frac{1}{2}(e^{2x}+1)\Longrightarrow$$

$$\int e^x\cosh x\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int(e^{2x}+1)dx=\frac{1}{4}e^{2x}+\frac{x}{2}+C=\frac{1}{4}\left(e^{2x}+2x\right)+C$$

As you did by parts doesn't work since $\,e^x(\cosh x-\sinh x)=e^x(e^{-x})=1\,$...

Comment: Without the `2` at the end.

Comment: ...and before the end, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$
\int \exp(x) \cosh(x) dx
$$

Write this as

$$
\int \exp(x) \cosh(ax) dx
$$

then

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \exp(x) \cosh(ax) dx &=& \exp(x) \cosh(ax)  - a \int \exp(x) \sinh(ax) dx\\
&=& \exp(x) \cosh(ax) - a \exp(x) \sinh(ax) + a^2 \int \exp(x) \cosh(ax) dx
\end{eqnarray}
$$

thus

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \exp(x) \cosh(ax) dx &=& \frac{ \exp(x) \cosh(ax) - a \exp(x) \sinh(ax)}
{ (1 - a)(1+a) }
\end{eqnarray}
$$

whence

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \exp(x) \cosh(x) dx &=& \lim_{a \rightarrow 1} \frac{ \exp(x) \cosh(ax) - a \exp(x) \sinh(ax)}{ (1 - a) (1 + a) }
\end{eqnarray}
$$

---

The last part - taking the limit gives

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \exp(x) \cosh(x) dx &=& \lim_{a \rightarrow 1} \frac{ \exp(x) \cosh(ax) - a \exp(x) \sinh(ax)}{ (1 - a) (1 + a) }\\
&=& \lim_{a \rightarrow 1} \frac{x \exp(x) [ \sinh(ax) - a \cosh(ax)] - \exp(x) \sinh(ax)}{-2}\\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \exp(x)\sinh(x) + \frac{1}{2} x
\end{eqnarray}
$$