# Is it possible to integrate $e^{x}\ \sinh(x)$ using only integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration, integration-by-parts

Is it possible to integrate $e^{x}\ \sinh(x)$ using only integration by parts?

If so, how would it be done?

I read the following Stack Overflow article, [Integrate $\int e^x \cosh(x) \: dx$ by parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301078/integrate-int-ex-coshx-dx-by-parts), which contains an arithmetic mistake.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can follow the answer about modifying the function to integrate $e^x\sinh(ax)$ and perform the limit $a\to 1$ in the result. -- The direct approach will again lead to a tautological result.

Comment: @LutzL, Thank you for your comment. How did you integrate exp(x)*sinh(ax) by parts?

Comment: Just follow the answer of johannesvalks in you linked question. But it is really a much too complicated way to get this simple integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int e^x \sinh x  =  e^x \sinh x-\int e^x \cosh x=e^x \sinh x - \int e^x (\sinh x + e^{-x})=e^x \sinh x - \int e^x \sinh x - \int 1 = e^x \sinh x - x - \int e^x \sinh x $

Gives: $\int e^x \sinh x =  \frac{e^x \sinh x-x}{2}$

Edit: I am using $\cosh x = \sinh x +e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 9):

$e^x \sinh(x) = e^x \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{2x} -1 \right)$. Why would you want to use integration by parts?

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  Set $\mathrm{e}^x = \cos(-\mathrm{i}x) + \mathrm{i} \sin( -\mathrm{i} x)$ and then use the usual method for trigonometric functions.

Although [Jon Warneke's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2021977/123905) is a much better way to attack this integral.

Comment: The reason I want to use integration by parts is for educational enrichment. Thank you.